# share data between two files through es6 class in mithril js or share instance of es6 class

Tags: javascript, global-variables, es6-class, mithril.js

I want to share data between two files in mithril js Im using webpack for module loading I have this class , Im getting data from ajax request and then storing it in class member given below.

```
import m from 'mithril';

import { myClass } from './model';
let asad=new myClass();
var Data = {


    fetch: function() {
        m.request({
            method: "GET",
            url: "./config/config.json",
        })
            .then(function(items) {
                asad.setConfig(items) // storing this data here .
                m.route(document.body, "/accounts", routes)
            })
    }

}
Data.fetch()
```

this is my class file

```
export class myClass {
constructor() {

}
setConfig(obj) {
  this.config= obj

 }
 getConfig() {
 return this.config;

}
 }
```

And in another file I want to get this data

```
import m from 'mithril';

import { myClass } from '../model';


 export function Accounts() {
  console.log('accon')
   let asad=new myClass();
   console.log(asad.getConfig())
   }
```

the problem is it create new instance of class how can I share instance of this class so that is works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by making ***singleton*** class in es6 using following code.

```
export class globals {

constructor() {
if (!globals.instance) {
  globals.instance = this
}
return globals.instance;

}
setConfig(obj) {
this.config= obj

}
getConfig() {
return this.config;
}

}
```

and then I'm calling get config method working perfectly